# Location of "start at login" items?

Tags: mac, startup, login-items

I have quite a few apps (Glui, Wunderlist, Cobook) that startup at login (which I do not want them to). I do not have them among the user's login items and when I created a new test user, these apps do not start.

I also checked in LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons (both system and User) and can't find these items there.

Where else can I look? I tried removing all the com.apple.loginwindow.* items from `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` and still these items start at login.

Answer (score 6):

The following list might help you to disable some program at startup :

1. Those in *System Preferences » Accounts » Login Items* (actually, these include the ones from 1.)
2. The login hook for `loginwindow` [described here](http://support.apple.com/kb/Ht2420), read current value with `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook`
3. Some of those specified as part of a `launchd` script (or otherwise managed by `launchd`). List all with `sudo launchctl list`. See `man launchctl` for details.

Regarding the `launchd` lists, you can see their definition files in the `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDaemons` subdirectories of your system's `Library` directories:

- `/System/Library` (you probably shouldn't touch these)
- `/Library/` (usually for all users)
- `/Users/yourname/Library` (your own programs)

In the latter two libraries, check for anything suspicious. It's usually XML, so you can open and read them.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I already checked all these locations and can't find anything! Any other tips?

Comment: @fnurl could you tell us which programs are starting ? It might help

Comment: I can't find Spotify in any of these locations even though it's still starting automatically somehow...there must be additional locations that control startup programs?

Comment: Since the answer is 9 years old, probably. But I don't have them... Good luck @Andy

Answer (score 1):

These apps could also be starting simply because they were the last items running when your account logged out, if you have the "reopen applications upon login" option checked.

[image]

This setting use a combination of saved application state in ~/Library and the status of launched applications from the launchctl daemon to re-start apps that were launched the previous session.